# How to send message between two clients by using HTML5 websocket and Ruby Event-machine?

Tags: javascript, ruby, html

I am using event-machine to make a chat room .

Here is the example code in their library(event-machine websocket)

```
require 'em-websocket'

puts "Server is listening!..."
EM.run {
    @channel = EM::Channel.new
    puts @channel.methods.sort
  EM::WebSocket.run(:host => "0.0.0.0", :port => 8080) do |ws|
    ws.onopen { |handshake|
      puts "WebSocket connection open"
      sid = @channel.subscribe {|msg|
          ws.send msg 
      }
      @channel.push "#{sid} connect!"
      ws.onmessage {|msg|
          @channel.push "<#{sid}>: #{msg}"
      }
      ws.onclose {
          @channel.unsubscribe(sid)
      }
    }
  end
}
```

How can I get the "sid" user information ? and keep connecting?

In client.html , it will become a new client after refreshing (F5)

I would like to make a one-to-one (send message between two clients) chat room,

but I don't know how to send message to specified user.(e.g.)sid1 send message to sid5.

Comment: Your code example has nested the ws.onopen, ws.onmessage, and ws.onclose calls. these should all be at the 'same' level, i.e., don't have the ws.onmessage inside the ws.onopen

Comment: The web socket connection will always get disconnected and will reconnect, as a new connection, when the page loads. The easiest way to keep the same connection active is to not refresh the browser page!

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I have a question that how can I keep the "same" connection active , like keep logining effect (keep the same information) , I want to make this to prevent user refreshing browser page. My idea is that using cookies or session to do this . Is there have ways to keep the same connection after refreshing? or it is impossible that it must be reconnected as a new connection after refreshing browser page.